# Skip an argument when doing a 301 redirect in NGINX

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-301

First post here.
So I'm using this code to redirect specific pages from one domain to another.

`if ( $request_filename ~ / ) { rewrite ^ https://example.net permanent; }`

Is there an option to skip anything including "?d=" in that code?
I don't want any pages after ?d= included in the redirect.

Answer (score 2):

If the rewritten URL ends with a `?`, `rewrite` will not copy any of the original arguments over.

For example:

```
rewrite ^ https://example.net/? permanent;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

---

Alternatively, use the simpler `return` expression:

```
return 301 https://example.net/;
```